# GWT: JsArray and JavaScript object

Tags: gwt

Am facing an issue while trying to implement an example given over a website.

One of the methods in a class has a signature like this -

private void updateTable(JsArray prices) {....}

And am trying to invoke this method from another method as -

updateTable(JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText()));

while doing this am seeing a compilation error as -

The method updateTable(JsArray) in the type StockWatcher is not applicable for the arguments (JavaScriptObject)

Though I have just used the exact code displayed in the website, am seeing this error. Not sure what needs to be done. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed by making the following change -

updateTable((JsArray)JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText()));

introduced a casting in the above statement.

Comment: You can use generics instead of a cast: `updateTable(JsonUtils.<JsArray<Whatever>>safeEval(response.getText()))`